# GTK+: GtkButton: set focus on click

Tags: gtk

I have a question that I think should not be too complex.

I have a toolbar of 4 buttons. For each button I call:

```
gtk_button_set_focus_on_click();
```

With the gboolean value FALSE.

This seems to work for all buttons except one: The first one is automatically selected and never gets deselected. It is the first button. It is created and added to a vbox just like the other ones, so I am not sure what could cause it to stay selected.

Does anyone has any clue why please?

EDIT:

I actually just figured it out, sorry. It has to do with the window itself, it did set my button as focused. To fix this problem, I called gtk_window_set_focus(); to set focus on another element. Not sure if this is the correct way to do, but it seems to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just figured it out, sorry. It has to do with the window itself, it did set my button as focused. To fix this problem, I called gtk_window_set_focus(); to set focus on another element. Not sure if this is the correct way to do, but it seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `gtk_widget_set_can_focus` helps (disable focus on Buttons' parent, HBox for example, or the window)

Comment: Just tried, it didn't seem to help. Thanks, it was a good guess.